# Is it "the business'" or "the businesses" responsibility?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

It's quite common in my company to make a distinction between "the business" and "the IT department".

I think this is the correct way to write what I want:
"It is the business' responsibility to set the policy, and IT's to implement it."

But then my spell checker keeps changing it to this:
"It is the businesses responsibility to set the policy, and IT's to implement it."

Should it be the first one?

Comment: Neither. "It is the business's responsibility."

Comment: None of the above. It's _the responsibility of the business_. Saxon genitives don't work well with non-animate nouns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither.  It should simply be this for one business:

> It is that business’s responsibility to set the policy.

And this for several businesses:

> It is those businesses’ responsibility to set the policy.

Those are pronounced the same, but spelt differently.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean "James' responsibility" instead of "James's responsibility" is wrong? Also, whilst I'm thinking about it, in my context is the business a proper noun, and should it therefore be capitalised?

Comment: *James's* is correct for something belonging to James. No, *business* is not a proper noun.

Comment: Interestingly enough Microsoft Word doesn't like business's, but it does like Business's.